# Aid Another vs a spell effect

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, helping

The [Aid Another rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#aidAnother) discuss how one character can make a special attack against AC 10 to grant +2 to attack rolls or AC to an ally. These rules have an addendum at the end (emphasis mine):

> You can also use this standard action to help a friend in other ways, such as when he is **affected by a spell**, or to assist another character’s skill check.

The case for skills is [adequately described](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#aidAnother) - you roll a skill check against DC 10. **But what do you roll when you want to help your ally "when he is affected by a spell"?**

I'm looking for written rules, not rulings. A DM might rule that you make a saving throw against DC 10, or still make an attack roll, or require a Spellcraft skill check, and that's fine, but what (if anything) do the rules actually say about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### If the [aid another](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#aid-another) action can assist a creature affected by a spell, that use of the aid another action is mentioned in the spell's description

There's no general way to use the [aid another](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#aid-another) action to assist an ally affected by a spell. Instead, a specific spell's description will mention how a creature can use the aid another action to assist an ally against a spell's effect. This makes the aid another action no help against most spells' effects.

For example, a creature can use the aid another action to assist an ally with the Escape Artist skill check (DC 25) necessary to free itself from the effects of the 5th-level Drd spell *blood creepers* [conj] (*PH2* 104). More common, however, is a creature using the aid another action to awaken from magical sleep an ally affected by an effect like the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*sleep*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#sleep) [ench] (*PH* 280) *et al*.

I suspect this part of [aid another](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#aid-another) was included in anticipation of future expansion then forgotten by most future authors.

Comment: Interesting point, I hadn't considered that spells would specify. Looks like the spells that support this are Sleep, Great Worm of the Earth, and the Oriental Adventures version of Spirit Needle. Enthrall and Blood Creeper have involved ability checks that are called out as being help-able with aid another.